# Query Object Array inside another Object Array

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

[image: Query-Mongodb]

I need to get the value "no_tilt" but I just cannot figure it out, I was trying something like this..

```
collectionName.find({
      "Shape.layers.vector_tagging": {
        $elemMatch: { "1.shapes": { $elemMatch: {0: "Label"} } }}
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I downloaded Robot 3T and started testing, and I was finally able to do it, here it is in case anyone finds it useful

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find({
      "Shape.layers.vector_tagging": {
        $elemMatch: { "shapes": { $elemMatch: {"tags.Label":"no_tilt"} } }}
      })
```